Laravel 11 Attempt to read property "name" on int
Laravel 11! When I try to list products in the blade template I get an error "Attempt to read property "name" on int"
EDIT: to be sure, I also send an export of the product table, foreign keys are defined.
In the blade template I pass the data as follows
<tbody>
@foreach($products as $product)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $product->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $product->category->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $product->subcategory->name }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>

My ProductsController.php
public function create(): View
{
    $products = Products::with(['category', 'subcategory'])->get();
    return view('products', compact('products'));
}

Models Products, Category, SubCategory
class Products extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'products';

    public function category(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }

    public function subcategory(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(SubCategory::class);
    }
}

class SubCategory extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'subcategory';

    public function products(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Products::class, 'subcategory', 'id');
    }

    public function category(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'id_category', 'id');
    }
}

class Category extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'category';

    public function subCategories(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(SubCategory::class, 'id_category');
    }

    public function products(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Products::class, 'category', 'id');
    }
}

I'm at a loss, I really don't know what to do anymore. I'm 90% sure I'm making a mistake somewhere in the models, in defining the relationship between the tables. But I'm not 100% sure. The worst part is that neither Google Gemini nor ChatGPT solved my problem, despite 2 hours of trying.
CREATE TABLE `ala_products` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `category` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `subcategory` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `color_1` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `color_2` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `min_size` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `max_size` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `order_x` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `active` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `ala_products_category_foreign` (`category`),
  KEY `ala_products_subcategory_foreign` (`subcategory`),
  CONSTRAINT `ala_products_category_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`category`) REFERENCES `ala_category` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `ala_products_subcategory_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`subcategory`) REFERENCES `ala_subcategory` (`id`)

public function up(): void
{
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name', 255);
        $table->string('slug', 255);

        $table->unsignedInteger('category');
        $table->foreign('category')->references('id')->on('category');

        $table->unsignedBigInteger('subcategory');
        $table->foreign('subcategory')->references('id')->on('subcategory', 'id');

        $table->string('color_1', 10);
        $table->string('color_2', 10);
        $table->smallInteger('min_size')->default(0);
        $table->smallInteger('max_size')->default(0);
        $table->smallInteger('order_x')->default(0);
        $table->enum('active', ['0', '1'])->default('1');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}


In your ProductController try dd($products) and check if name column really exist?Also check what should be your table name products or ala_products?

Edit your question and also share the migration file for Products model

Try to dd($products) and check if the relations are correctly loaded, and if u can maybe share the category and subcategory migrations here :), i think the relations are the issue here

It seems like in the SQL you provided, the table name is ala_products, but in your Product model, you've set the $table to products. Why?

@Subha done and thanks :)

@DishanSachin in config/database.php settings i have in connections: 'prefix' => 'ala_', laravel automatically work with this :)

@MichaelGrznár, What did you get while doing dd($products)?

@MichaelGrznár, Ensure that generated table name after running migration are categories & subcategories not category & subcategory. Because by default migration files generate plural form of the name as per naming convention. Also add this into your Product migration file  $table->foreign('subcategory')->references('id')->on('subcategory');  removing id.And also check whether generated table name is subcategory or subcategories.

@Subha https://imgur.com/a/fDY5ixn It returns null, but I don't know why, because when I look in the database, the product is in the database and it correctly matches to the other keys, i.e. categories and subcategories :(
I removed the id from the migration file and ran it again, unfortunately the problem persists

@MichaelGrznár, Got it , I have posted my answer .Please check and let me know if there is any issue still exist after implementing my solutions.Thanks

Instead of re running migration you can also create a new migration file to change the foreign_key column name as suggested in my answer @MichaelGrznár.


Attempt to read property "name" on int

It is the naming-conventon issue.
You already have a category & subcategory column in products table and a in your product-model you have also defined relationship with the same name i.e. category() & subcategory(). This is the reason you are getting error mentioned above while accessing related model value either with this $product->category->name or with this $product->subcategory->name.
Solution:-
You need to redefine the products migration file. Just do these changes and run the migrations file again by appending _id to the foreign_key .
    $table->unsignedInteger('category_id');
    $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('category'); // properly mapped the related table based on name

    $table->unsignedBigInteger('subcategory_id');
    $table->foreign('subcategory_id')->references('id')->on('subcategory'); // properly mapped the related table based on name

Try this. it will work for sure.
N:B:-

Ensure the table name is category & subcategory not categories & subcategories respectively.


Works! Thank you <3 small bug on line "$table->foreign('subcategory_id')->references('id')>on('subcategory');" there's a missing hyphen and $table->unsignedInteger('category'); and $table->unsignedInteger('subcategory'); must look like this $table->unsignedInteger('category_id'); and $table->unsignedInteger('subcategory_id'); THANK YOU MUCH!

@MichaelGrznár, You are most welcome. Because of hurry I made those mistake.BTW thanks for your correction.
